# Transform Json data from ajax request

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm new to JS and React. I get a json object from an ajax that looks like this:

```
{     "resultData": [
    {
        "modulname": "Physics",
        "passed": "passed",
        "not passed": "",
    },
    {
        "course": "Physics",
        "passed": "",
        "not passed": "not passed",
    },
    {
        "course": "English",
        "passed": "",
        "not passed": "not passed",
    },
        "course": "English",
        "passed": "",
        "not passed": "not passed",
    },
    ...
```

I don't know how many objects this array will contain and what courses there will be. In addition I want to calculate the amount of people who passed the course.
My goal is to get an array of objects like this, where I can map over and create react elements:

```
results [
        {
           course: "Physics",
           passed: "50%"
        },
        {
           course: "English"
           passed: "65%"
        },
        ...
        ]
```

How to find a good solution for this?

Comment: Please share what you tried or thought about so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to collect the data and map them then for the print:

```js
var res = {
  "resultData": [
    {
        "course": "Physics",
        "passed": "passed",
        "not passed": "",
    },
    {
        "course": "Physics",
        "passed": "passed",
        "not passed": "",
    },
    {
        "course": "Physics",
        "passed": "",
        "not passed": "not passed",
    },
    {
        "course": "English",
        "passed": "",
        "not passed": "not passed",
    },
    {
        "course": "English",
        "passed": "passed",
        "not passed": "",
    }
  ]
}

var result = res.resultData.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    var found = acc.find(x => x.course === curr.course);
    var passed = curr.passed && 1 || 0;
    var notpassed = curr["not passed"] && 1 || 0;
    if (found) {
        found.passed += passed;
        found.notpassed += notpassed;
    } else {
        acc.push({ course: curr.course, passed: passed, notpassed: notpassed });
    }
    return acc;
}, [])
.map(function(r) { return { course: r.course, passed: Math.round((r.passed / (r.passed + r.notpassed) * 100)) + "%" }; });

console.log(result);
```